# Remove element using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to print the text inside the div but it should not include the text inside `<ul>`
It should only print out text inside `<p>` and `<blockquote>`

My HTML

```
<div class=abc>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <blockquote>some text</blockquote>
  <ul>some content</ul>
</div>
```

I am this code to extract the div and print it.

```
  Elements e = doc.select("div.abc");
  for (Element p:e){
    System.out.println(p.text());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already selected `div.abc` and you want to select its `<p>` and `<blockquote>` elements you can add

```
e = e.select("p, blockquote");
```

right after `Elements e = doc.select("div.abc");` to select its `p` OR `blockquote` elements.

---

You can also do the same in one select

```
Elements e = doc.select("div.abc p, div.abc blockquote");
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you enter the `for`-loop: `e.remove("ul");` removes the entire node.